# Can I bring this integral into a form involving known functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-functions, quantum-field-theory

In the context of quantum field theory, I am facing the following $1$-dimensional integral over Feynman parameters:

$$I(a,b) = \int_0^\infty d\alpha \frac{1}{F G} \arctan \frac{F}{G} \tag{1}$$

with

$$F(\alpha, a , b) := \sqrt{\alpha(1+\alpha)(a-b)^2-\alpha a^2+(1+\alpha)b^2} \tag{2}$$

$$G(\alpha, a , b) := \sqrt{\alpha \left(a-b-\alpha(a-b)^2\right)} \tag{3}$$

**Added details**: $a$ and $b$ are $4$-vectors in Euclidean space with $a^2 = 1$. Thus $b^2 > 0$ and $(a-b)^2 >0$.

Is there a way I can express this integral with, I don't know, polylogarithms or elliptic functions? Usually, my (rather primitive) method to reach this goal is to put the indefinite integral into Mathematica, pray that it can solve it, and take the appropriate limits. But this time, Mathematica can't do it, so it makes me wish for a more robust method to do that.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ here? Surely the integral won't converge for any value of them. Are you trying to find only some specific values?

Comment: @Zacky I have added some details, sorry for forgetting to specify that. Yes the integral should be logarithmically divergent, and the divergence is cancelled by the contribution coming from another integral. Does that mean that I would not be able to express it in terms of other functions? Maybe I should do the other integrals first, and then try to combine them.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to mention the original integral too in the question body.

Comment: @Jxx The function $G$ isn’t well-defined as written. It looks you are trying take the square root of a four-vector. Is this a typo?